# Symfony Translations not loaded with true required

Tags: symfony, translation

The translation working perfectly like this :

```
 ->add("address", TextType::class, [

           "label" => "adresse_tr",
           'translation_domain' => 'adminTR',
           "required" => false,

     ])
```

but doesn't work without required or with **"required" => true**

```
 ->add("address", TextType::class, [

           "label" => "adresse_tr",
           'translation_domain' => 'adminTR',

     ])
```

Comment: Do you have customized the rendering of the form field labels or are you using some library/bundle that does it? Because I think the problem could be only there (from the few info you provided).